# Finding longest continuous string patterns inside string and erasing it

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I was wondering since I could not find any similar topics, what is the best way 
to find continuous string patterns in the string and erase them from it.

What I mean by that is :
I've got string : "AAAAaaCCCCCCcDDDEEEE" , and I would like to find the longest same continous string and that would be CCCCCC since C occurs 6 times, and then delete it from the string so I would get "AAAAaacDDDEEEE", then do it over and over again until there will be only one continous string.  I've tried doing it on my own but it seems to take more lines of code that its simplicity calls for,

Please help

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: `'AAAAaaCCCCCCcDDDEEEE'.match(/(.)\1*/g).sort((a,b) => b.length-a.length)[0]`

Comment: What do you want to happen if there are two or more equally long longest strings?  In `"AAAAAAaaCCCCCCcDDDDDDeEEEE"`, the runs of `A`s, `C`s, and `D`s are each six characters long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could find continuous characters and replace with an empty string.

```js
var string = "AAAAaaCCCCCCcDDDEEEE",
    longest = string.match(/(.)\1*/g).reduce((a, b) => a.length > b.length ? a : b);
    
console.log(longest);

string = string.replace(longest, '');

console.log(string);
```

With a function.

```js
function remove(string) {
    var longest = string.match(/(.)\1*/g).reduce((a, b) => a.length > b.length ? a : b);

    while (longest.length > 1) {
        string = string.replace(longest, '');
        longest = string.match(/(.)\1*/g).reduce((a, b) => a.length > b.length ? a : b);
    }
    return string;
}
    
console.log(remove("AAAAaaCCCCCCcDDDEEEE"));
```

Comment: Lets say that it is a function, how can i execute it n times, every time returining value string based on the rule that it stops when there will be no continous characters in the string?

Comment: what do you mean by *"be no continous characters"*? should it have only single characters?

Answer (score 0):

Another option is just an old-fashioned `while` loop. This will have significantly more performance than using a regex at the expense of more code and (a little) less readability:

```js
let s = "AAAAaaCCCCCCCcDDDEEEE"

let start = 0, max = 0, current = 0, maxStart = 0
while(current <= s.length) {
  if (s[current] !== s[start]){   
    if (current - start > max){
      max = current - start 
      maxStart = start
    }
    start = current
  }
  current++
}

// the found string:
console.log(s.substring(maxStart, maxStart+max))

// delete
s = s.slice(0,maxStart) + s.slice(max + maxStart) 
console.log(s)
```

Comment: Lets say that it is a function, how can i execute it n times, every time returing value after deleting part of string based on the rule that it stops when there will be no continous characters in the string?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regexp to get an array of chains. Get the length of the longest chain with [`Math.max()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) and [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Use [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to remove the longest chains, and than combine back to a string with [`Array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

This will handle multiple long chains with the same length.

```js
const removeLongest = (str) => {
  const chains = str.match(/(.)\1*/g); // get an array of chains
  const longest = Math.max(...chains.map(s => s.length)); // find the longest chain length
  return chains.filter(({ length }) => length !== longest) // remove longest chains
    .join(''); // convert array back to string
};
   
console.log(removeLongest('AAAAaaCCCCCCcDDDEEEE')); // AAAAaacDDDEEEE
console.log(removeLongest('AAAAaaCCCCCCcDDDEEEEEE')); // AAAAaacDDD
```

Comment: Lets say that it is a function, how can i execute it n times, every time returing value after deleting part of string based on the rule that it stops when there will be no continous characters in the string?

Comment: You start by marking one answer (probably Nina's) as accepted. Afterwards, you open a new question with what you want. You can supply some of the code here, if it makes you more comfortable.

Comment: Did that , dont know how stackoverflow works but is the owner of the solution gonna be informed about my edit / changes?

Comment: Don't update the question. People already answered it. Open a new one. You can roll back the update